# CD/DVD burner error "writing isn't supported"

Tags: dvd, burner

**ISSUE DESCRIPTION**

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS yesterday. When I connected to the internet, Ubuntu showed a message with available updates, so I updated my software.

The problem is that I cannot get any of the following burning applications (mentioned below) to write to a disc.

There are currently no issues with my Ubuntu installation.

I'm learning how to make audio music CD's, so I installed `K3b`, `Brasero`, and `Xfburn` trying to test my DVD writer on Linux, but all three of these applications failed at writing DVD or CD discs. At one point, I received an error message that writing isn't supported.

I used my laptop writer before when I was using Windows to burn some CD's and I made it successfully.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I tried some solutions shown in some other askubuntu qustions but, there's no result.

I checked my DVD writer with this command:

```
pascal@pascal-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15AST:~$ cat /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/info
CD-ROM information, Id: cdrom.c 3.20 2003/12/17

drive name:        sr0
drive speed:        24
drive # of slots:    1
Can close tray:        1
Can open tray:        1
Can lock tray:        1
Can change speed:    1
Can select disk:    0
Can read multisession:    1
Can read MCN:        1
Reports media changed:    1
Can play audio:        1
Can write CD-R:        1
Can write CD-RW:    1
Can read DVD:        1
Can write DVD-R:    1
Can write DVD-RAM:    1
Can read MRW:        1
Can write MRW:        1
Can write RAM:        1
```

Comment: Obvious question... are you using CD-R or DVD-R new discs?

Comment: I used both, CD blank discs, and DVD blank discs, and failed in both to burn anything.

Comment: What make and model of computer and how old is it?

Comment: It's not old, it's some good, it's "Lenovo ideapad 330" laptop.

Comment: 'I tried some solutions' Could you be more precise, so we do not propose things that you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
# in your case
device="/dev/cdrom"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, but **there is one more step**.

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: I did what you mentioned and found that I forgot press the refresh button in Xfburn - for example- to recognize the blank DVD disc, but after that a new error message appeared "Failure: Cannot reserve track of 2162688 bytes", the DVD blank disc was 4 Gb.